# Spring Boot Application Unable to start?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am still a beginner in Spring Boot and I am trying to learn how to use Spring Data JPA. I was trying to get a query parameter from my controller and then add that data to MySQL database using Spring Data JPA. But I am getting this strange error and I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I tried so far.

```
Home Controller
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Home;
import com.example.demo.service.HomeServiceImpl;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private HomeServiceImpl sh;

    @RequestMapping("/homedata")
    public Home Hello(@RequestParam("name") String name){
       Home s = sh.fetchinfo(name);

       System.out.println("sss"+s);
        return s;
    }


}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.demo")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.demo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.example.demo")
public class SpringUnitTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringUnitTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Model class

package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "personal")
public class Home {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;



    public Home(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Hello" + getName();
    }



}


Service layer


 package com.example.demo.service;

    import com.example.demo.model.Home;

    public interface HomeService {
        public Home fetchinfo(String name);


    }

package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.model.Home;
import com.example.demo.repository.HomeRepository;

@Component
public class HomeServiceImpl implements HomeService{

    @Autowired
    private HomeRepository rs;

    @Override
    public Home fetchinfo(String name){
        Home s = new Home(name);
         rs.save(s) ;   
        System.out.println("This is from service layer"+s);
        return s;
    }



}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.Home;



public interface HomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Home, Long> {



}
```

Maven
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringUnitTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringUnitTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Logs -

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.8.RELEASE)

2017-10-29 21:41:37.407  INFO 6200 --- [           main] c.e.demo.SpringUnitTestApplication       : Starting SpringUnitTestApplication on VAIO with PID 6200 (C:\Users\user\workspace\SpringProjects\SpringUnitTest\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\workspace\SpringProjects\SpringUnitTest)
2017-10-29 21:41:37.417  INFO 6200 --- [           main] c.e.demo.SpringUnitTestApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-29 21:41:37.671  INFO 6200 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15710fc: startup date [Sun Oct 29 21:41:37 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-29 21:41:39.638 ERROR 6200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional;
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.postProcess(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:127) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringUnitTestApplication.main(SpringUnitTestApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]

2017-10-29 21:41:39.648  INFO 6200 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15710fc: startup date [Sun Oct 29 21:41:37 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-29 21:41:39.651  WARN 6200 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15710fc: startup date [Sun Oct 29 21:41:37 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringUnitTestApplication.main(SpringUnitTestApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]

2017-10-29 21:41:39.652 ERROR 6200 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15710fc: startup date [Sun Oct 29 21:41:37 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringUnitTestApplication.main(SpringUnitTestApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: remove all annotations except @SpringBootApplication from your SpringUnitTestApplication class. Then try and let me know your scenario.

Comment: @Zenith:- after removing 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field rs in com.example.demo.service.HomeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.HomeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.HomeRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: follow the code example given here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing versions, and not pulling in the boot starter for data jpa.

Please see this blog post that details how to and why you shouldn't do this. https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

You should only need to declare the following dependencies,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```