# SpringBoot fails with compatability problems

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.phoneBook.Main</start-class>
    </properties>

    <groupId>SpringProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.phoneBook.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I try to load a simple SpringBoot project it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.unwrapOptional(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.<init>(RelaxedDataBinder.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:197)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.phoneBook.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

I understood from reading posts here that it's an issue of compatability with dependencies. I was trying to use different versions without success.

It's not a duplicate of: [Spring Boot Application Unable to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004174/spring-boot-application-unable-to-start)

I added the dependencies shown there and I still got the same error.

Comment: You are mixing versions of spring and spring boot. Spring boot is built of spring, you should not do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Application Unable to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004174/spring-boot-application-unable-to-start)

Comment: @Bax, I added stack trace

Comment: @DarrenForsythe, I removed spring-context dependency and did mvn install, and I still got the same error

Comment: @DarrenForsythe, it's not a duplicate. I tried what the answer to that post suggested.

Comment: @CrazySyntax Please change maven plugin version to 1.5.10.RELEASE and why do you add Junit as.a seperate dependency please replace it with spring-boot-starter-test && logging(logback) is also available with starter-web.

Use spring.io.initializer to kick start boot projects.

Comment: I changed maven plugin version to 1.5.10.RELEASE and removed junit and still no change

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? You could also try clearing out your repository once and building again.

Comment: I did mvn dependency:tree and searched for 'core' and 'context'. found nothing

Comment: @CrazySynthax it is a duplicate. You have mixed versions of Spring and boot which are incompatible and have not cleaned and built the project properly again. Please read the spring blog which is linked in this issue and understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

By the error we can see there is a version mismatch between `spring-context` and `spring-core` :

```
178:  public DataBinder(@Nullable Object target, String objectName) {
179:     this.target = ObjectUtils.unwrapOptional(target);
180:     this.objectName = objectName;
181:  }
```

To check which version of each is used run :

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep 'spring-context\|spring-core'
```

You can go further and check the actual packaged version, it should be the same as shown by maven :

```
jar tf SpringProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep 'spring-context\|spring-core'
```

If it shows :

> BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar
>   BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar

and the error still persists, please post a complete source sample and steps to reproduce it.

Comment: I removed 'spring-context' from pom.xml and I still got the same error.

Comment: @Bax Since the class in question (ObjectUtils) comes from spring-core, wouldn't it be more helpful to grep that instead?

Comment: @Bax True, but then OP removed the context dependency, so that explanation shouldn't apply anymore

Comment: I changed spring-boot-maven-plugin version to 1.5.0.RELEASE. Still, no change.